# Multi arrays in text file

Tags: javascript, datatables

Im using Datatables that via ajax gets multi text files in the following format:

```
{ "aaData": [
    [ 10126, 10002253, 415 ]
] }
```

The problem is here that getting multi files is bad because of the latenency for first byte, so i would like to merge all the data into one file and tried the following format:

```
{ "aaData1": [
    [ 10126, 10002253, 415 ]
] 
"aaData2": [
    [ 10126, 10002253, 415 ]
] }
```

i also tried basicly merging al the files ( into one ), and i off course have renamed aaData to something usefull.

**Question boils down to what is the correct format to have multi arrays in 1 text file?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct method is:

```
{ "aaData1": [ 
    [ 10126, 10002253, 415 ] 
],  
"aaData2": [ 
    [ 10126, 10002253, 415 ] 
] }
```

Notice I was missing a comma